# update multiple tables column values depending on data in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables in my application one is mdl_moog_groups and moog_assigncourses..

so in both tables groupid is common column

so groups are created by superadmin..and for every group superadmin going to assign courses

if they are any courses assigned to the group if they are going to delete the group  i need to update both status columns in  both tables to '0'

if they is no courses assigned to the group it will update only groups table status column to '0'..

In my case what happened is if there are no courses assigned to the group..if i try to update the column its not updating..it showing error..

i tried a lot..but its not working properly..i don't know..
here is my code

```
 <?php 
 require('../config.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['can_access']) || $_SESSION['can_access'] !== true ) 
 header('Location: login.php'); 
global $DB,$USER; 
//$id=$USER->id; 
  $deleted_on = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
 echo $id = $_GET['id'];
 $sql= "update mdl_moog_groups SET deletestatus = '0' where  WHERE 
 mdl_moog_groups.id ='$id'";

  $sql.="update mdl_assigncourses set delete_status = '0' WHERE 
  mdl_moog_groups.id ='$id' and groupid != '0'";

 if ($DB->execute($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "Record updated successfully";
  } else {
  echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
 }
header("Location:groups.php"); 
?>
```

can anyone help me out..how to do this..
thanks in advance..

Comment: Write a query for those if conditions which in your question

Comment: can you please explain me brief how to write if conditions for that query..i am trying to dofrom morning but i couldn't can you please explain me please

Comment: Put your code in question then i can help you

Comment: i updated my question..can  you please check once..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For delete you can do something like these:

```
update mdl_moog_groups set deletestatus = '0' WHERE id ='$id';

update mdl_assigncourses set delete_status = '0' WHERE id ='$id' and groupid != '0';
```

Example:

```
$sql = "update mdl_moog_groups set deletestatus = '0' where  WHERE mdl_moog_groups.id ='$id';";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

execute both query line by line or you can [multiple queries](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp) also.

same thing you can do for :

"if they is no courses assigned to the group it will update only groups table status column to '0'.."

Comment: i used like that before...if courses assigned to the group how can i change the column status value to '0'..how to use that..

Comment: In that case, you have to check with where condition something like "and where groupid != 0"

Comment: it showing error like this Debug info: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE mdl_moog_groups.id ='42'update mdl_assigncourses set delete_status = '0' W' at line 1
update mdl_moog_groups SET deletestatus = '0' where WHERE mdl_moog_groups.id ='42'update mdl_assigncourses set delete_status = '0' WHERE mdl_moog_groups.id ='42' and groupid != '0'
[array (
)]

Comment: Check updated also try your self to find errors and bugs otherwise you can't learn

Comment: i updated my answer as per your answer..can you please check whether i did any mistake...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154879/discussion-between-ahmed-ginani-and-user3663).